# angular 4 unit testing error `TypeError: ctor is not a constructor`

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-routing

I am trying to test my route resolver and while testing I got `TypeError: ctor is not a constructor` and no idea why it happen while typescript compile time no error.

```
TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
    at _createClass (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42355:26)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42330:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42315:17)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42362:26)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42330:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:42315:17)
    at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:43401:16)
    at TestBed.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js.TestBed.get (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:48412:47)
    at http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:48418:61
    at Array.map (native)
```

Comment: are you using ng2 bootstrap

Comment: yes. but I am testing route resolver. is that effecting my route resolver even there is not html or css

Answer (score 296, accepted):

This can be an error in the providers declarations.

When you try to mock a provider and use useClass instead of useValue the error "TypeError: ctor is not a constructor" is fired.

Here is an example that fires the error :

```
providers: [{provide: OrderService, useClass: new OrderServiceMock()}]
```

The correct declaration is :

```
providers: [{provide: OrderService, useValue: new OrderServiceMock()}]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error while doing `{ provide: httpTestingControllerToken, useClass: HttpTestingController },`, where I declared `const httpTestingControllerToken = new InjectionToken<HttpTestingController>('httpTestingControllerToken');`... this is when trying to replace the deprecated [`TestBed.get`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes). Any ideas?

Comment: So when do you useClass vs useValue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same message when building my app with AOT.

My problem was not related to providers as @abahet suggested.

It was because I setup a new library which was not AOT compliant (and didn't have any provider either). The library in question had to **export** (I'm talking about Typescript export, not the one from Angular module) what was imported in the module (in this case, a component and a pipe).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Angular Universal in combination with Firebase in a Firebase Universal Starter project. I had almost lost hope as all the potential fixes on stack overflow didnt help. So I did the following:

1. Update all npm packages with https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates
2. Remove node_modules and .package-lock.json and reinstalled them
3. Fixed all errors due to changed api's
4. Now it was working :-)

I never found out what package caused error, but one approach to find out is to create a MockAppModule where you remove modules one by one. Eventually you will find the one with the problem. But in my case I got lucky I guess due to one of the bugged packages got updated or something.

Answer (score 1):

Third possibility for you, I had a module containing other modules and didn't export (Typescript speaking) the other modules.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem with AOT enabled.I added a new service file. I restarted the compiler and the issue is resolved.