# NgRx 7.4.0: Uncaught TypeError: ctor is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am struggling to work out why I am not able to register my effects using NgRx version 7.4.0. I have totally stripped back my effects class looking for a solution to this problem but I am still receiving the following error:

```
main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:33529 Uncaught TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
    at _createClass (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:33529)
    at _createProviderInstance (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:33501)
    at initNgModule (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:33432)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:34161)
    at Object.createNgModuleRef (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:34150)
    at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:36687)
    at main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:30069
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.f00ff83aa2c2b28f8bcd.js:7646)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.79a79285b0ad5f8b4e8a.js:29604)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.f00ff83aa2c2b28f8bcd.js:7645)
```

The module definition looks like this:

```typeScript
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({settings: settingsReducer}),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([SettingsEffects])
    ],
    declarations: [/*..other declarations..*/],
    exports: [/*..other exports..*/],
    providers: [/*..other providers..*/],
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

The dependencies in my `package.json` look like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/effects": "7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "7.4.0",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0"
  },
```

My dev dependencies look like this:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "7.2.15",
  "@angular/compiler": "7.2.15",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.15",
  "@angular/core": "7.2.15",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.15",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.15",
  "@angular/router": "7.2.15",
  "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.9",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
  "@types/jest": "19.2.4",
  "@types/node": "7.0.43",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
  "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
  "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
  "core-js": "2.6.10",
  "del": "2.2.2",
  "gulp": "3.9.1",
  "gulp-header": "1.8.9",
  "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
  "gulp-replace": "0.6.1",
  "gulp-rollup": "2.14.0",
  "gulp-shell": "0.6.3",
  "inquirer": "3.2.2",
  "jasmine-marbles": "0.6.0",
  "jest": "23.6.0",
  "jest-preset-angular": "6.0.2",
  "node-sass": "4.5.3",
  "node-sass-tilde-importer": "1.0.0",
  "node-watch": "0.5.5",
  "rollup": "0.42.0",
  "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
  "rxjs": "6.5.3",
  "rxjs-compat": "6.5.3",
  "ts-node": "7.0.1",
  "tslint": "5.20.0",
  "typescript": "3.2.4",
  "zone.js": "0.8.17"
}
```

The `SettingsEffects` class — which I have stripped back in case the problem lay in the effects class itself — looks like this:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class SettingsEffects {

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions
    ) {
    }

}
```

In its original state, the `SettingsEffects` class yields the same error.

If I remove this line:

```typescript
EffectsModule.forRoot([SettingsEffects])
```

from the imports, the app launches successfully; but of course the effects don't run, which is no good.

I have searched on the world wide interweb but there are no clues to why this is happening. This module is in a library imported by the main GUI of the app, and we have been careful to make sure there are no package version clashes: everything is using versions 7.4.0 of the store modules.

Please help! Been pulling my hair out for a day over this now!

Comment: you can try and provide an empty array to the forRoot and see what happens:     EffectsModule.forRoot([]),

Comment: Also have a look at this discussion => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597532/angular-4-unit-testing-error-typeerror-ctor-is-not-a-constructor

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cant use `forRoot()` for feature module like this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({settings: settingsReducer}),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([SettingsEffects])
    ],
    declarations: [/*..other declarations..*/],
    exports: [/*..other exports..*/],
    providers: [/*..other providers..*/],
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

Try to change like this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        StoreModule.forFeature("settings", settingsReducer),
        EffectsModule.forFeature([SettingsEffects])
    ],
    declarations: [/*..other declarations..*/],
    exports: [/*..other exports..*/],
    providers: [/*..other providers..*/],
})
```

Also the correct way to init store for feature is provide 2 argument not passing in object like your are doing right now

```
StoreModule.forRoot({settings: settingsReducer}) // this is wrong

StoreModule.forFeature("settings", settingsReducer) // this is correct
```